# What may cause failure of displaying letter M?

Tags: fonts

What may cause failure of displaying letter M?

[image]

Extra: what is the best place for the questions related to encodings / displaying failures?

UPD20211113. Link to the affected document: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1918617.pdf.

In contrast in the [similar document](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1920272.pdf) from the same manufacturer the M is ok:
[image]

The properties "Application", "PDF Producer", "PDF Version" (see `File => Properties` in Acrobat Reader) of affected and non-affected documents are the same. Then what (potentially) may happened that now there are displaying failures?

Comment: Normally it's caused by using a character not present in the font. Which program are you using? Do you have the font installed or are you perhaps working with some *subset* of the font? Are you editing something made by someone else? Or have you perhaps pasted in the text? What happens if you manually enter an M where it's missing?

Comment: There’s no way to answer this as asked – there’s just not enough information. We don’t even know what your image is showing – it could be anything.

Comment: Hm. Is there any possibility you're using a demo product, font or software, with some characters removed to make it impossible to use commercially?

Comment: Generally speaking, that could be caused by a missing glyph in a font. The "glyph not found" character is a rectangle.

Comment: to add to comments above: Where/when is the dropped glyph ocurring? i.e. is this an exported-to-PDF rendering? A screencap of the rendering within a technical software package?

Comment: Is there any possibility that what you're using is some kind of demo product? I've seen fonts with a character taken out so it can't be used commercially.

Comment: @Wolff See UPD20211113. Can you please analyze the affected document?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet See UPD20211113. Can you please analyze the affected document?

Comment: @Copilot See UPD20211113. Can you please analyze the affected document?

Comment: Well, it’s not actually an M at all. It’s a `›` (right single guillemet), for some reason. You can see this if you copy-paste the text into a simple text document. But there’s also something odd about the bounding boxes of the text – if you select text in the PDF, the colour that highlights the selected text doesn’t match up with the actual text you’ve selected. This is especially clear if you select the “no ???o??? ?on???to” bit, where the highlight is only about five characters long. I don’t know what software was used to create the PDF, but something buggy happened.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet _what software was used_: see `File => Properties` in Acrobat Reader.

Comment: Oh yeah – InDesign CS6, apparently. Perhaps a bit odd is that there seem to be a mixture of TrueType and PS1 versions of Helvetica embedded in the file. That is possibly related, but lacking more serious PDF sleuthing skills than I possess, I doubt it’s possible to find out what has led to this particular bugginess.

Comment: I agree it looks strange. It's hard to tell what happened here. Would be easier if you had the original InDesign files, but the way you ask makes me think you don't. The graphics in the PDF could come from some other source and the error could be introduced when placing the graphics in InDesign. So it's some error with the font or wrong handling of the file somewhere in the unknown process of making the file. Why do you ask btw?

Comment: @Wolff _Why do you ask_: Because each time I'm amazed that in the 21th century such issues are still possible. I was thinking that such issues are subject of the 20th century. See also: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/33928/modern-video-encoders-decoders-keep-producing-compression-artifacts-what-is-the (If you know someone who can answer, then please pass the question).

Comment: @pmor, haha I'm thinking directly *opposite*. I don't have the sense of living in "the future". I have tiny problems like this almost everyday with client documents. People shovel data around without knowing much about what's going on. So we have to constantly "repair" data in different ways. Higher complexity leads to more digital mess (but perhaps also quicker fixes?).

Comment: Looking closer, it’s clearly not just M that’s missing, but quite a lot of characters. The “no ???o??? ?on???to??” bit surely isn’t meant to be all Ms missing; rather, it looks like it’s supposed to say “no [something] connectors”. Creating a font inventory report from the PDF shows that there are two different subset-embedded PostScript Helveticas in the file: one Type 0, one Type 1. Of lowercase letters, the Type 1 has only bmot, and the Type 0 about half the alphabet. So if it should say “connectors”, it’s using at least the n from the Type 0 and trying to use the Type 1 for the rest.

Comment: Or rather, that seems like it was probably the case in the _originating software_ – that is, the CAD/technical drawing app where the actual drawings were produced. This would not have been InDesign. The drawings (with their text) were presumably placed in InDesign as EPS or PDF files. At some point, perhaps when exporting in the drawing app, some sort of transcoding issue turned all missing glyphs into “›”, and since that glyph doesn’t exist in the (subset) PS fonts, it’s replaced by the `.notdef` glyph, the black square.

Comment: **Edit:** Hang on, the Type 1 font also has l, n and y – they were just hiding in a different part of the table and I missed them. So it’s just the Type 1 font being used to write “no [something] connectors”. That makes a lot more sense. It also has the uppercase letters required to write “TER_INAL”, but not the M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just simply means that the font didnt have these glyphs (letters) when the pdf was generated, when it was laid out or when the pdf was rendered. Its not a encoding issue.

Why would this happen? There is no information available your guess is as good as ours. It could be any of multiple things heres a partial list of things I have encountered:

- Demo version of font, where letters are intentionally left out.
- Font was retrieved from a PDF file that had only a subsets of glyphs available.
- Font in generating system is corrupted.
- There is a bug in subsetting code.
- Production system mangled the font name and downstream system couldnt retrieve font correctly (there are some software that are quite notorious on this front, several cad applications and matlab come to mind) and operator/system didnt catch this.
- Some software added pages to the PDF without considering about font subsetting
- Your PDF is corrupted or broken
- The PDF creator has a bug in its implementation.
- Your PDF viewer is retrieving old version of font data, either this is a cache issue or the viewer does for some reason not read the newest font definition in appended flle for example..
- ...